# Find the set of all the subsets of {}.

Tags: combinatorics

I am getting confused with a couple of questions. It would be great if someone could help me out.Thanks in advance.

2. Find a pair set S such that:
   (a) {1} does not belong to S and {1} is not a subset of S.
   (b) {1} belongs to S and {1} is not a subset of S.
   (c) {1} does not belong to S and {1} is a subset of S.
   (d) {1} belongs to S and {1} is a subset of S.

Comment: What is a "pair set" beyond just a set?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Take a look at [How to ask a good question at Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). To avoid downvotes and closing you should add your own efforts to the question, and tell us where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If $\{1\} \in S$ then $S=\{\{1\}, \dots \}$.

If $\{1\} \subset S$ then $S=\{1, \dots \}$.